# Why does this Python list comprehension give list index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
grid = [[]]
[j for j in range(len(grid[i])) for i in range(len(grid))]
```

gives `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I think `i` can be only `0` and `[j for j in range(len(grid[0]))]` runs fine without any problem. So I am confused.

Comment: You need to switch the order of the two `for` clauses (I always get confused on that, too).  The IndexError happens because `i` was previously assigned to value of 1 or higher, and gets used in your list comprehension before it's assigned a new value.

Comment: ```[j for i in range(len(grid)) for j in range(len(grid[i]))]```

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the nested lists, use `copy.deepcopy(grid)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when running the snippet as is Python complains about `i` not being defined, and not about the index error: `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

In Python, if you don't wrap the left part, `j for j in range(len(grid[i]))`,  in another list, you read the for loop inside a list comprehension like you would in a conventional one, so at the moment you reach `grid[i]` it has no idea what `i` is.

As Beulah Evanjalin commented, what you're trying to achieve would work with:

```py
# reading order ---->
[j for i in range(len(grid)) for j in range(len(grid[i]))]

# Input: grid = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] 
# Output: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

But things are different if you make the left loop a nested list comprehension, where it is actually read after the one on the right:

```py
#                                        <---- reading order
[[j for j in range(len(grid[i]))] for i in range(len(grid))]

# Input: grid = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] 
# Output: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Note: It would be nice to add the main goal of the question, so we have what to compare with the answers.